# How can I delete all builds expo.io?

Tags: react-native, build, expo

I’d like to delete all android builds expo. How can I do that?

This would help to quickly resolve some issue with signing errors upon profile changes. Right now I have created a different account to force the build to new certs and profiles.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete credentials by using -c flag (expo build:android -c), this clears your Android keystore from the build servers (read more about it [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps/#3-start-the-build))

Comment: Sorry I tried it but it doesn’t work. It’s rebuilding. Can not delete. "expo build:android -c" Sorry. Can you write a example code?

Comment: "expo build:android -c" is a command you run in your terminal. It doesn't delete builds, it clear your credentials for that app and creates new ones.
I suggest you look through the Expo documentation- https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/distribution/building-standalone-apps/